# Unique row in data frame based on another column value

Tags: python, dataframe

> This is the data frame

```
        Date     name    Age 
0   2015-01-02  Adam       1   
1   2015-02-02  David      2   
2   2015-02-02  Adam       2   
3   2015-03-02  David      2   
4   2015-03-02  Hardik     2   
5   2015-03-02  David      3
```

Now I need to unique the name column with respect to Date column. In other words unique name column per month.

This is the expected output

```
        Date     name    Age 
0   2015-01-02  Adam       1   
1   2015-02-02  David      2   
2   2015-02-02  Adam       2   
3   2015-03-02  David      2   
4   2015-03-02  Hardik     2
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'name'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove dups:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2015-01-02', '2015-02-02', '2015-01-02'], 'name': ['A', 'B', 'A'], 'Age': [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'name'])
print(df)
```

You can use `df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'name'], keep='last')` for last appearance.

outputs:

```
         Date name  Age
0  2015-01-02    A    1
1  2015-02-02    B    2
```